# Transformation of angular momentum operator as a tensor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry

[image]I’m currently reading the book from Steven Weinberg on Quantum Mechanics and I’m struggling with the following.

If V is some vector observable is rotated, then for a symmetry transformation there must be a unitary operator U such that

U−1(R)ViU(R) = ∑  RijVj
U−1RViUR = ∑  RijVj

```
                                                     (1)
```

For an infinitesimal rotation
Rij = δij+ωij +O(ω2)
Rij = ij+ij +O2

our U operator has the form

U(1+ω) = 1 + i2ℏ∑  ωijJij +O(ω2)
U1+ = 1 + i2ℏ∑  ijJij +O2

```
                            (2)
```

Where J is the generator of the symmetry transformation. According to the book, if we use the equation (2) into (1) we get the following

iℏ[Vk , Jij] = δikVj − δjkVi
iℏVk , Jij = ikVj − jkVi

I feel like I’m missing something about the index notation. How does the author gets these indexes and delta symbols? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please use latex/mathjax for your equations. You can use dollar signs $ to enclose equations. No need to use a picture.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can find how to do nice math on this page, it'll help people answer and understand you a lot better.

Comment: Oh, if you like an answer please consider accepting it, and up voting is also a small kindness you can do to repay God answers.

Answer (score 0):

This relation holds for arbitrary, infinitesimal $\omega_{ij}$. Substituting (2) and the infinitesimal rotation into (1) we get:

$$(1 - \frac{i}{2 \hbar} \omega_{lm} J_{lm})V_i(1 + \frac{i}{2 \hbar} \omega_{np} J_{np}) = (\delta_{ij} + \omega_{ij})V_j  + O(\omega^2)$$.

To leading over in $\omega$ we get

$$-\frac{i}{2\hbar}\omega_{lm}[J_{lm}, V_i] = \omega_{im}V_m $$

We can write $\omega_{im}$ as a sum over a delta function, $\omega_{lm} \delta_{li}$ and noting that $\omega_{lm}$ is antisymmetric then we can write $\omega_{lm} = \frac{1}{2}(\omega_{lm} - \omega_{ml})$. This holds for arbitrary $\omega$ and hence you get the result.

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful